# Generate SSH key on computer A and use it to SSH from computer B to computer C

Tags: server, ssh

I'm doing some provisioning work, and it happens that I now need to do something I've never done before that I'm completely stumped on how to do.

I need to be able to generate an ssh key pair (ssh-keygen -t rsa) on one system, let's call it System A, and then transfer that pair to System B & System C in such a way that I can ssh from System B to System C. In other words I need an ssh key pair where I don't actually have to generate the key on any of the systems that will be ssh-ing.

How do I do this?

Comment: I have to ask, if systems B and C have SSH, why don't you want to generate the keypair on system B? then you'd only need to copy the public key to C's `.ssh/authorized_keys` for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On system A:

```
mkdir /tmp/my-keys
cd /tmp/my-keys
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f some-name
```

it will generate a `some-name` file containing the private key, and a `some-name.pub` file containing the public key.

Next, copy the `some-name` private key to system B (the one you want to connect from). Place it in the .ssh directory for the user you'll connnect as. If the user doesn't have an .ssh directory, create it by running `ssh-keygen` in that system; or, if you don't want to (I think this is your whole point), manually create the directory, copy the `some-name` file into it, and ensure `.ssh` has mode 700, and the `some-name` file is 600. Both should be owned by the user in question.

Finally, copy `some-name.pub` public key to system C (or any system you want to be able to connect to, from B). Place it in the `.ssh` directory for the user you'll connect as. Rename it to `authorized_keys`, this is the list of keys SSH will examine; any private key which matches the given public keys will be allowed to connect.

Comment: This worked for me, but only if also renamed the private key copied over to system B to 'id_rsa'.